# Laptop screen goes dark and flickers when power cord unplugged

Tags: laptop, display

I have an issue with an ASUS X55MA laptop. I've just reinstalled Windows and this was happening before. It appears when the power cord is unplugged the laptop screen just goes really dim and flickers.

- I have tried changing to High Performance, Balanced and Power Saver.
- I've tried downgrading and installing the latest drivers.
- I've also tried altering the power plan default brightness in the
  advance settings as the per the post here;
  [Laptop screen turns off on removing power cord](https://superuser.com/questions/666410/laptop-screen-turns-off-on-removing-power-cord)

I am running the latest BIOS and latest version of Windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a hardware problem. Try the following:

- If you have another battery, try that one
- Make sure it is charged 100% (although it shouldn't matter, it's better than an almost empty).
- Measure the voltage of the battery and check if it according to the specs of your laptop.

These rule out at least the major part of any hardware problems related to power.

Comment: Annoyingly the battery is built into the laptop and I don't really want go opening it up. My next assumption was driver comparability although, on the ASUS website you are able to select Windows 10 in the OS version so I presume they are supported.But yes, the battery is 100%.