# Why does my screen go black every time I unplug laptop?

Tags: windows-10

I have a Lenovo laptop with Windows 10 already installed on it. I have not updated it or anything. I got it four months ago.

Why does my screen go black every time I unplug laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Your battery might be damaged or check your Power options settings in control panel. Check the on battery settings of display. Your computer might be set on sleep or off if unplugged.

Comment: i can still see the screen, just very very dark, on lowest light setting possible when i unplug it, so its not shutting off or anyhting or going to sleep, but you would tell from two feet away if it was on, and then cant put brightness back up after i unplug it, have tried going on settings, but couldnt find what to do

Comment: There's a Super User [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/666410/laptop-screen-turns-off-on-removing-power-cord) that relates to the same issue

Comment: ok its good now, didnt do anything but its not doing it anymore